# Solve optimization problem with python library which has a logarithmic objective function

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization

How can I solve optimization problem:

[image]

subject to:

[image]

(I am looking for a library that its objective function can accept logarithms.)

I found `glpk` and `gurobipy` but they don't seem to be able to do it.

Comment: You need to show us more of your own work - SO doesn't exist to do homework for you. When you encounter a specific problem - i.e., when you have an attempted solution, or at least a partial solution, we can help you with what's going wrong and why.

Comment: Oh no! I think there is a misunderstanding. I am looking for a library whose objective function can accept logarithms.

Comment: Oh, okay, that's a much better question. At least to me, it was super unclear you were asking that - maybe edit your post to include the word "library" in the title, and removed the "piece of code" phrase - that line in particular really threw me.

(I don't know any such library, but good luck!)

Comment: You need a general-purpose NLP solver for this, or a conic solver that knows about the exponential cone.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments under the question, I am just going to refer you to one of the more standard libraries to solve this problem. Note the your objective concave and its a maximization problem. So, it is straightforward to rewrite it as a convex minimization problem and your constraints are linear. For such problems, you can use CVXOPT(https://cvxopt.org/index.html). In particular, look at some of the examples for how to use the library: https://cvxopt.org/examples/index.html#book-examples

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with something like Scipy's optimize function.
You only need to specify your objective in the way you wish to utilize above.

Here is how that could look:

```py
import scipy
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

vars = [var1,var2,var3, var4,...]  ## assuming there are many variables

### Define objective: 
def objective(x, sign  = -1.0, *args):   ## scipy optimize only has a minimize function so we apply -1 to get the max.
    obj = np.sum(np.log(x[i]) for i in vars]
    return sign * obj

#### Define constraints:
def cons1(x, *args):
    return c - (x[0] + x[1])

def cons2(x, *args):
    return c - (x[0] + x[2])

def cons3(x, *args):
    return c - (x[0] + x[3])

def cons4(x, *args):
    return c - (x[0] + x[4])

...

### Solve the problem
x_init =  [0.0 for each in vars]    ##(initiation for each variable)                                              

cons = [
{'type':'ineq', 'fun': cons1},
{'type':'ineq', 'fun': cons2},
{'type':'ineq', 'fun': cons3},
{'type':'ineq', 'fun': cons4},
]

solution = scipy.optimize.minimize(obj , x_init, 
                                   method = 'trust-constr',   
                                   bounds = b, 
                                   constraints = cons, 
                                   options={'maxiter': 1000, 
                                             xtol' : 1,
                                             gtol' : 1e-3,
                                             verbose': 0,
                                             disp': True
                                            } 
                                               )

### trust-constr : Works well with non-linear problems and all types of constraints - most brute force approach
```

I have used this approach for one of my recent projects, revolving around log-transformations in the objective function found this to be 1 of the few working processes.

Hope this helps!